# In password reset view custom templates not loading?

Tags: python, django

[image]I am working on rest password via  custum templates in django,but  custom template not loading it is loading django's default template every time i load the /password_reset/ url.

I am using the url

```
 url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

i have a registration folder in templates and using this link to work 
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html

and the template folder is:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))),
                 ],

        'APP_DIRS': True,

        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                "cms.utils.context_processors.permission_based_hidding_of_sidebar",
            ],
            'libraries':{
                'template_tag': 'cms.templatetags.template_tag',
                'template_tag_time': 'cms.templatetags.tags',
            }
        },
    },
]
```

install apps in settings:-

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'cms',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'django_csv_exports',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.admin',


]
```

Comment: Did you created `password_reset` template files in your directory?

Comment: yes i have a registration folder in my templates where i have created password_reset.html templates

Comment: Can you include your project structure in your question? I also want to know that where is your registration folder ?

Comment: just uploaded my project structure with settings.py is there and at the bottom of templates registration folder where i have all the templates

Comment: 'DIRS': [os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) You should refer to the template directory path --------> 'DIRS': [os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'templates')

Answer (score 2):

See my comment below. Sure, you can hack it and remove the form in the distribution library. Very very naughty. A much better solution is to **alter** the order in which the apps are loaded in your settings file. Originally I had:

> INSTALLED_APPS = ['django.contrib.auth', 'ana_access',]

I just changed this so my app loaded first. And lo. That did it.

> INSTALLED_APPS = ['ana_access','django.contrib.auth', ]

Conclusion: if you keep seeing the default page DESPITE having the form in your templates/registration folder, then it might be because you are loading the default django.contrib.auth app before your own.

Answer (score 1):

Django 3.0. 2020. I solved the issue by adding template/registration/*.html  in the project directory. This solved my issue.  I don't need to change anything in the INSTALLED_APPS list.

Here are the steps:

1. Do the following highlighted changes in "settings.py"

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], # **ADD THIS
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static', # * (optional)
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

2. Create templates/registration directories in your project root folder and add your registration templates here instead of your_app/templates/registration.

```
Project_root_folder/templetes/registration/*.html
```

*No need to change anything in INSTALLED_APPS of settings.py*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the Django admin template you need to created `admin` folder inside your templates directory. And place all your admin's files and folders there...

```
templates
|__ admin
    |__ registration
```

Update: Also please correct the TEMPLATES DIR It should be

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Comment: place all your admin files means the one I want to override or all the files because the one I want to override I put that in the admin panel and it's not working.

Comment: You need to override registration templates right. So create a folder called `admin` in `templates` and place the registration folder...

Comment: but it still shows the Django templates..not the custom templates

Comment: @AbiWaqas Sorry for the late reply. I updated my answer. Please check

Comment: As of March 2020: the override does NOT work. I have customized the password_reset_form.html and placed it in my template/registration folder. But Django does not find it. So finally I found the default file password_reset_form.htm in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration and changed its name. And now it works: django has to go to my local templates (yes, very messy and hacky).